# The boundary between superconducting and not-superconducting states. Are there any observable phenomena there?

Tags: phase-transition, superconductivity

Imagine we have a long cylinder of a superconductor and we conduct the following experiment: one end of this cylinder we keep below the critical temperature, so it is in a *superconducting* state, while the other end is kept at room temperature, so it is in a *not-superconducting* state.

I have read the answers in this question: [Superconducting wire with temperature gradient](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/375740/superconducting-wire-with-temperature-gradient) and as I understood there will be some boundary region where *the competitions between the two phases* will occur, so called nucleation.

My question is the following. Will there some macroscopically observable phenomena happen there? I mean somethng like electrical polarization and the electric potential difference between the ends of this cilinder, due to the different behaviour of electrons at both sides?

Are there any articles related to this topic?